# I want to hide the channel/side-bar in discord.com

Tags: css, firefox

I wanted to be able to remove the sidebar in discord but it isn't working. I tried url(*specific channel url*) and domain(discord.com). I'm using the latest version of firefox. Here is the code in my userContent.css file:

```
@-moz-document domain(discord.com) {
    .sidebar-2K8pFh{  /*that is the class of the sidebar and I checked that it doesn't change*/
        width: 0px;
    }
}
```

It works when I type it in to the temporary stylesheet in developer tools but not from my userContent.css file. I am new to this and if you could, could you give a more detailed explanation on what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Welp I didn't try restarting firefox!